# Entlib Loading the data inMemory

Tags: caching, enterprise-library

I am using caching library from EntLib 3.1, we are storing quite heavy data in the caching db around (300 meg), when I instantiate the  CacheFactory.GetCacheManager("Cache Manager"), it returns the Heavy List of cache object from database, which resulting in Application to be using very high memory, Is there a way to not load the entire data in the inmemory of the application using entlib, instead of loading the item ondemand from the cache database itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Entlib caching block stores a copy of the cached items in memory. The backing store is there for persistence across app restarts. There's no way to change this behavior.

Comment: I have modified this behavior in Open Source, I am not loading anything in backingstore and extended the behavior to support OnDemand Load and store the items in-memory as you use it instead of loading all the Items from the database when you initialze the Cache Instance, this allowed my application to scale beautifully...